# How do I create a new column that that contains part of a string based on a pattern in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

Apologies if this has been solved before, I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem. I am trying to pull out the letter "N" out of a sting including the -1 and +1 position and report it in a new column, there may be more than one instance of N in the string and i would like it to report all of them. I can filter the peptides containing N using
`dt_contains_N <-dt[str_detect(dt$Peptide, "N"),]`
but I'm not sure how to extract it, I was thinking something like ,
`dt_N_motif <- dt[substring(dt$Peptide, regexpr("N", dt$Peptide) + 1)]`
but im not sure how to include the N-position column information to extract the N-1, N and N+1 positions.
For example a simplified view of my data table looks like:
`dt <- data.frame(Peptide= c("GESNEL", "SADNNEW", "SADNNEW"), N_pos=c(4,4,5))`
.
.

| peptide | N pos |
| --- | --- |
| GESNEL | 4 |
| SADNNEW | 4 |
| SADNNEW | 5 |

and I would like it to look like this:

| peptide | N pos | Motif |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GESNEL | 4 | SNE |
| SADNNEW | 4 | DNN |
| SADNNEW | 5 | NNE |

Any help would be great,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substr`/`substring` to extract the string present between  `N_pos - 1` to `N_pos + 1`.

```
transform(dt, Motif = substr(Peptide, N_pos - 1, N_pos + 1))

#  Peptide N_pos Motif
#1  GESNEL     4   SNE
#2 SADNNEW     4   DNN
#3 SADNNEW     5   NNE
```

Comment: incredible! That was so much simpler than I realised. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dt %>%
    mutate(Motif = str_sub(Peptide, N_Pos -1, N_pos + 1))
```